# How can I take a different values from different tables and store in another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to take the `customer id` from a `customer table`, `restaurant id` from a `restaurant table`, and `order id` from `order table`. I want to store these values in a single table detail. How might I do this?

Comment: Not to be rude but, huh? It sounds to me like you want to create a detail table with those 3 ids in it...but I suspect I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Varun Sharma, if you want you can write the code in C# where you can get all the values from all tables and club in to a single table and display in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

If, there's a common column in every table which can be useful to make joins, then you can use 'join' keyword for that purpose and can also refer [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa976856%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: how would you find the link between customer id, restaurant id, and order id? you need some link between these three tables in order to retrieve the intended result set before inserting in to the new table. Please provide some more details on it.